# How to get Ubuntu Host to Register Hostname With DNS Server

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, dns, dhcp, hostname

I'm in an Active Directory domain.

I have a windows computer (not joined to the domain). When I connect it to the network, I can ping it by hostname from any other computer on the network.

How can I replicate this behavior on Lubuntu 16.04?

I've tried samba/winbind. I got somewhere with avahi, but that doesn't appear to work across different subnets.

If my unjoined windows computer can do it so effortlessly, then there HAS to be a way with Ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: Typically the DHCP server will register the FQDN in DNS for the host. The client has to send the host name option in the DHCP request ttho.

Comment: OK, so then I need to tinker around with /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf, then, @vidarlo?

Comment: I would guess so, but I'd not be surprised if ad does it some totally different way...

Comment: Check out my answer below @Vidarlo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you to @Vidarlo.

I went back to my dhclient.conf file (`/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`), where I had tried submitting the fqdn already, but I admittedly cut and pasted code I saw from other discussion forums. I had the following,

```
send fqdn.fqdn "myhost.my.corp.domain";
send fqdn.encoded on;
send fqdn.server-update off;
```

but the `send fqdn.server-update` should have been set to `on`.

Then, to release your lease with the DHCP server and get a new lease run the following commands:

```
sudo dhclient -r
sudo dhclient
```

And now it works!

Comment: Will this work with home routers? They have built in DHCP and tell clients that the router is the dns server? But are they real DNS servers or just DNS repeaters?

Comment: For completeness to help other people trying to solve this problem, it would be helpful to note the location of the dhclient.conf file: /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf on 16.04

Comment: The path that I mentioned in my comment on the question?

Answer (score 2):

> Very simple and elegant solution for using SSSD based integration -
>   https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jeffbutte/2016/12/18/265/ - just
>   set FQDN as linux hostname:
>
> ```
> hostnamectl examplename.mydomain.mysuffix
> ```

actually **set-hostname** is missing, it should read:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname examplename.mydomain.mysuffix
```