# Register hostname in active directory DNS in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dns, dhcp

I'm on ubuntu 18.04 which is part of an active directory domain using sssd.

How can get my ubuntu to register its hostnmae to the dns server.

I saw [How to get Ubuntu Host to Register Hostname With DNS Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990537/how-to-get-ubuntu-host-to-register-hostname-with-dns-server) which seems to not apply to 18.04 has it's not using dhclient ?

I did not find anything in netplan to do this.

I found a way to do it with systemd-networkd: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450032/systemd-networkd-dhcp-hostname-option but it's not doing it and I don't any error message anywhere regarding the fact that networkd is trying and failing.

Any idea ?